# Connection STM Nucleo expansion module to STM 32 NUCLEO

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, embedded, interface

I want to connect a STM I-NUCLEO-LRWAN1 Expansion module to a STM32 Nucleo  microcontroller.

However, there are no documentation on how this is achieved:
http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-eval-tools/stm32-3rd-party-evaluation-tools/i-nucleo-lrwan1.html

Are there some general rule with expansion modules? Do they simply fit ontop of the MCU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These boards are essentially like the shields for the Arduino. You plug it into the Nucleo by inserting the pins into the inner female headers of the nucleo. It will only fit one way so won't be too hard to fit.

Make sure you have a pinout diagram handy!